# Code does not work as Joomla modul - shopping cart

Tags: php, session, joomla, joomla-extensions, joomla3.0

i have built a simple shopping cart in php and as a standalone version it works fine.
Now I tried to get it working as a Joomla Module. But when you are now call this function to product will be added the first time twice and then for each call three times. And when you add a other product then it gets more crazy with the quantity.
I can't make it out where the mistake could be :(

Hope you can help me ;)

```
public static function addProduct($product_code) 

    {
        $db = JFactory::getDBO();
        //MySqli query - get details of item from db using product code
        $db->setQuery("SELECT product_name FROM #__osmaf_products WHERE product_code='$product_code' LIMIT 1");

        // Load the row.
        $result = $db->loadResult();

            //prepare array for the session variable
            $new_product = array(array('name'=>$result, 'code'=>$product_code, 'qty'=>1));

            if(isset($_SESSION["products"])) //if we have the session
            {
                $found = false; //set found item to false

                foreach ($_SESSION["products"] as $cart_itm) //loop through session array
                {
                    if($cart_itm["code"] == $product_code) //the item exist in array
                    {
                        $qty = $cart_itm["qty"]+1; //increase the quantit
                        $product[] = array('name'=>$cart_itm["name"], 'code'=>$cart_itm["code"], 'qty'=>$qty);
                        $found = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //item doesn't exist in the list, just retrive old info and prepare array for session var
                        $product[] = array('name'=>$cart_itm["name"], 'code'=>$cart_itm["code"], 'qty'=>$cart_itm["qty"]);
                    }
                }

                if($found == false) //we didn't find item in array
                {
                    //add new user item in array
                    $_SESSION["products"] = array_merge($product, $new_product);
                }
                else
                {
                    //found user item in array list, and increased the quantity
                    $_SESSION["products"] = $product;
                }

            }
            else
            {
                //create a new session var if does not exist
                $_SESSION["products"] = $new_product;
            }
        return;

    }
}
```

Comment: Have a look at this for your database query: http://docs.joomla.org/Selecting_data_using_JDatabase

Comment: $result = $db->loadObject(); this is what i change.. but i have still the same problem.

Comment: no, you need to change the whole query. have a look at the examples on the link I provided

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing your code below:

```
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$db->setQuery("SELECT product_name FROM #__osmaf_products WHERE product_code='$product_code' LIMIT 1");

$result = $db->loadResult();
```

with this:

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();

$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select($db->quoteName('product_name'))
 ->from($db->quoteName('#__osmaf_products'))
 ->where($db->quoteName('product_code') . ' = '. $db->quote($product_code));

$db->setQuery($query, 0, 1);
$results = $db->loadObjectList();
```

Comment: The upper part is nice and i understand it. But for the last two lines shouldn't i use $db->setQuery($query); "$results = $db->loadObject();" and access it with "$results->product_name" ? Because i only want one value which is matching to the product name.

Comment: Now i got it...  $db->setQuery($query);
  $product_name = $db->loadResult(); and the problem was that the module is implementet serveral times and so it add itemes twice or three times.

Comment: Glad you got it working :) .... `$db->setQuery($query, 0, 1);` the number `1` that you see here is used to set the limit ;)